# laravel - custom lists method, with conditions

Tags: php, list, laravel

I'm trying to create a custom "lists" method in my repository so I can pass an array of conditions but it's not working.

```
public function lists( array $conditions, $value, $key, $distinct = false )
{
  $query = $this->model();

  foreach( $conditions as $keyvalue => $columnvalue )
  {
    if( $keyvalue == 'id' )
    {
      $query->where($keyvalue, '=', $columnvalue );
    }
    else
    {
      $query->where($keyvalue, 'LIKE', '%'.$columnvalue.'%');  // Non-empty string for example; posted a story id
    }
  }

  if( $distinct )
  {
    return $query->distinct()->lists( $value, $key );  
  }
  else
  {
    return $query->lists( $value, $key );
  }
}
```

Any help appreciated, it returns all values and ignores the where clause.

Comment: In what way is it `not working :(`, any error messages, stacks traces, visual cues are extremely helpful

Comment: Show how you create the array $conditions

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. It returns no errors, it brings back a collection but not filtered by the conditions I have passed. The conditions are just an array of key/value pairs such as array('name' => 'charles'). The conditions are being built but then ignored when I call the lists command.

Comment: Fixed, modified the line which reads  $query = $this->model(); to read $query = $this->model()->select(); Thanks for your help.